# Is there a way to make clickable/interactable particles in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to create a bubble-pop mechanic where bubbles will fall from the top of the screen, and the player will be able to 'pop' them by clicking/tapping on them.

Basically this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OH4dcpSk7n0

I started by creating a particle system. But is there a way to attach a script to the particle? Or should I go about it in a completely different way?

Comment: As far as I'm aware you can't add scripts to individual particles, your best bet would probably be to instantiate a `GameObject` with a `Circle Collider 2D` (or a `Sphere Collider` if you're in 3D), and then just use Raycasts to detect collision and destroy them that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should not use particles to achieve this, instead you should make a GameObject with rigidBody and collider attached to it, and spawn those GameObjects in the position you want.